# html bootstrap display paragraph beside image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The image is basically exactly what I want. However, I need the text paragraph to be aligned with the top of the image. There must be an easy way to get it to move up. I have no idea what it is though? Thanks!
[image: Result]

```css
#homePost {
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #fff, 0 0 0 12px #888;
    margin-right: 25px;  
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

```html
    <div class="well well-sm" style="border: 2px solid chartreuse; background: white;">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
               <p><h4>Toronto Maple Leafs Sucking again this year.</h4></p>
               <p>Date Posted: 24th of June, 2016</p>
               <p style="padding-top: 5px;"> </p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
                    <img style="float:left" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0kmH.png" id="homePost">
                    <span style="float:right"> 
                       <p>TEXT GOES IN HERE </p>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add margin-top: 20px;

Like this:

```
#homePost {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #fff, 0 0 0 12px #888;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[See This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1LOo.png)

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the text like `align-top` then use `vertical-align: text-top;` which will look like this `.align-top { 
    vertical-align: text-top;
}`